# How to cat a UTF-8 (no BOM) file properly/globally in PowerShell? (to another file)

Tags: powershell, utf-8, powershell-4.0, byte-order-mark

Create a file `utf8.txt`. Ensure the encoding is UTF-8 (no BOM). Set its content to `€`

In `cmd.exe`:

`type utf8.txt > out.txt`

Content of `out.txt` is `€`

In PowerShell (v4):

`cat .\utf8.txt > out.txt`

or

`type .\utf8.txt > out.txt`

Out.txt content is `â‚¬`

How do I globally make PowerShell work correctly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Note: This answer is about *Windows PowerShell* (up to v5.1); **[*PowerShell (Core) 7+*](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/README.md)**, the *cross-platform* edition of PowerShell, now fortunately **consistently defaults to *BOM-less* UTF-8** on both in- and output.

---

**Windows PowerShell**, unlike the underlying .NET Framework<sup>[1]</sup>
, **uses the following defaults**:

- **on *input***:<sup>[2]</sup> files *without a BOM (byte-order mark)* are assumed to be in **the system's *default* encoding**, which is the ***legacy* [Windows code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page)** ("ANSI" code page: the active, culture-specific *single-byte* encoding, as configured via Control Panel).
- **on *output***: the `>` and `>>` redirection operators produce **UTF-16 LE** files by default (which do have - and need - a BOM).

File-consuming and -producing cmdlets do **usually support an `-Encoding` parameter** that lets you specify the encoding explicitly.
**Prior to Windows PowerShell v5.1**, using the underlying `Out-File` cmdlet explicitly was the only way to change the encoding.
In **Windows PowerShell v5.1+**, `>` and `>>` became effective aliases of `Out-File`, allowing you to change the encoding behavior of `>` and `>>` via the `$PSDefaultParameterValues` preference variable; e.g.:
`$PSDefaultParameterValues['Out-File:Encoding'] = 'utf8'`.

**For Windows PowerShell to handle UTF-8 properly, you must specify it as both the input and output encoding<sup>[3]</sup>
, but note that on *output*, PowerShell *invariably adds a BOM to UTF-8 files.***

Applied to your example:

```
Get-Content -Encoding utf8 .\utf8.txt | Out-File -Encoding utf8 out.txt
```

To create a UTF-8 file *without* a BOM in PowerShell, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66553739/45375).

---

<sup>[1] .NET Framework uses (BOM-less) UTF-8 by default, both for in- and output.

This - intentional - difference in behavior between Windows PowerShell and the framework it is built on is *unusual*. The difference went away in PowerShell [Core] v6+: both .NET [Core] and PowerShell [Core] default to BOM-less UTF-8.</sup>

<sup>[2] This applies to [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) and notably also to *source code* read by the PowerShell engine. Unfortunately, the default behavior *varies across cmdlets*; for instance, [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv) assumes UTF-8. For an overview of the default character encoding used by all  built-in cmdlets in Windows PowerShell, see the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40098904/45375).</sup>

<sup>[3] Cmdlets such as `Get-Content` do, however, automatically recognize UTF-8 files *with* a BOM, and so does the PowerShell engine when reading source code.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

For PowerShell 5.1, enable this setting:

Control Panel, Region, Administrative, Change system locale, Use Unicode UTF-8
for worldwide language support

Then enter this into PowerShell:

```
$PSDefaultParameterValues['*:Encoding'] = 'Default'
```

Alternatively, you can upgrade to PowerShell 6 or higher.

https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell